# Clone a database pointed by ODBC connection to SQL-Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I have an ODBC connection to a database and I would like to clone it (as best as possible) on a SQL-Server database (for reasons that are not in scope of the question). Anyone have an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a one time clone, as opposed to keeping the databases in synch continuously, you could just do an SQL dump from the first and import to the latter.

Edit:
I'm not clear on the details of a dump through ODBC, but a quick search came up with this tutorial. It looks helpful:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879311%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: One time clone is good. How would you do a SQL dump from an ODBC database? instructions?